# Why create go types based on other?

Tags: go

what is the purpose of defining new types in go:

```
type NewType OldType
```

since NewType have only methods declarations, so:

```
var x NewType
```

can store also OldType 'objects'. Are there any advantages?

Answer (score 6):

The reason behind naming types in general is fairly straightforward, and is much the same in most languages - being able to name complex types, like:

```
type Person struct{
    name String
    age  uint8
}
```

However, naming a type like you described, which I'll call "type aliasing" (not sure if this is used by anyone else, but it's the term I tend to use), doesn't give you the above-mentioned advantage. What it *does* give you, however, is the ability to add methods to existing types. Go disallows you from adding methods to existing types that you did not define yourself (ie, built-in types or types defined in other packages), so aliasing allows you to pretend that you *did* define them yourself, and thus add methods to them. Another good way to think about it is like a much more concise version of creating a wrapper type (as you would in an OO language like Java, for example).

So, let's say that I wanted to be able use integers as errors. In Go, the `error` interface simply requires a method called "Error" which returns a string. Using type aliasing, I could do:

```
type errorCode int

func (e errorCode) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", e)
}
```

...and I could use integer error codes. By contrast, if I tried the following, I would get an error:

```
func (e int) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", e)
}
```

To demonstrate, check out this implementation:
http://play.golang.org/p/9NO6Lcdsbq

Just to clarify (because my use of the word "alias" may be misleading), two types which are otherwise equivalent (for example, `int` and `errorCode` in the above example) are not interchangeable. The Go type system treats them as fundamentally different types, although you may be able to type-cast between them.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Type aliasing is available in languages such as Scala and produces a *single* type with more than one name. Go has a better way: new types are distinct, they are *not* aliases. So for example, "type Distance float32", "type Time float32" and "type Speed float32" would allow a strongly typed "func CalcSpeed(d Distance, t Time) Speed" based on unambiguous types. This allows the compiler to do a lot more thorough checking than if you just had "func CalcSpeed(d float32, t float32) float32".

Comment: Sorry, my use of the word "aliasing" might have been misleading. I did mean to imply that it's a new type. I'll edit to correct.

Comment: _Why_ doesn't Go allow defining new methods on existing types?

Comment: There may be more reasons that I'm not thinking of, but off the top of my head, it could change the behavior of an imported package. So, for example, say I have a package that defines a type, and I use reflection to inspect the methods that are defined on my type. If a different package imported my package and defined new methods, it would change the behavior of my package in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 3):

> The Go Programming Language Specification
>
> [Types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)
>
> A type determines the set of values and operations specific to values
>   of that type.

You want identify a specific set of values and operations.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Coordinate float64

type Point struct {
    x, y Coordinate
}

func (p *Point) Move(dx, dy Coordinate) {
    p.x += dx
    p.y += dy
}

func main() {
    var p = Point{3.14159, 2.718}
    fmt.Println(p)
    p.Move(-1, +1)
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Output:

```
{3.14159 2.718}
{2.14159 3.718}
```

Comment: Yep. It's not only advantageous to use typing, but required sometimes, since you can't declare functions on primitive types.

Comment: @Matt: In Go, it's methods not functions: "A type may have a method set associated with it." [Method sets, The Go Programming Language Specification.](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

Comment: Okay, fine, semantics aside, I was referring to the "func" keyword. :P

Comment: @Matt: The Go `func` keyword is used for both [Method declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) and [Function declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations), which are distinct. Only methods are associated with a base type.